# Blender keeps replacing textures

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

So I've been working on this model and whenever I close it, one the textures keeps getting replaced by one of the other textures and its really infuriating. As you can see in the image, the texture preview shows that its not the same as the one being shown. Can someone help?[image]

Comment: So you want to use texture on which "LET'S" is written ? Can you post picture how your Shader Editor workspace looks like ? Which texture is set to be used there.

Comment: Hi, 'annoyed'. Welcome. We need information, to answer questions. Please share a stripped down version of the file with the minimum content that manifests the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/. Is your file reverting to a default file-path for textures, every time it opens, for example?